# Triggering specific interrupts in Linux Kenel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, microbenchmark

I'm working with the Linux Kernel and I need to drive specific types of interrupts (either from userland or kernelspace but it doesn't really matter to me, as I've set up a trampoline between them) as I'm benchmarking and working on the interrupt handler. Is there any standard way of driving interrupts (ie: device, disk)? As far as disk interrupts, I could write a userland program that simply reads/writes files, but I can't guarantee that it'll actually go to the disk - even if I flush the buffers, it's ultimately up to the filesystem.

Any advice would be awesome. Thanks!

Edit: To clarify more of what I'm trying to do:

1. Start a cycle counter timer (I've got this part down, as well as #3 and #4)

**2. Run some workloads (lots of disk interrupts, lots of network interrupts, lots of device interrupts)**

3. End the cycle counter timer
4. Dump the cycle counter data, and repeat for various workloads.

Comment: *"I need to drive specific types of interrupts"* -- What does that mean?  Before you muck around with system-critical devices, you could play with an auxiliary device such as a UART.  Just send (or receive) a character to generate an interrupt.

Comment: @tangrs I'm using `proc_dointvec` to dump some numbers to procfs, I don't think that's all that hacky. I could be wrong. I spent days trying to learn how to use ftrace and couldn't get it. As I mentioned in the last comment, I'm trying to benchmark the different types of interrupts in `/drivers/char/random.c`